# How do I parse json correctly?

Tags: python, json

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

def downloadPage(url):
    webpage = urlopen(url).readlines()
    return webpage

json_string = downloadPage('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=The%20Terminator')

str1 = ''.join(map(bytes.decode, json_string))

parsed_json = json.loads(str1)

print(parsed_json)
```

Seems like the json is not parsed properply and when I do

```
print(parsed_json['extract'])
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Universitet/PythonProjects/myapp.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(parsed_json['extract'])
KeyError: 'extract'
```

How can I make it work so it extracts the json I want with

```
print(parsed_json['extract'])
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: Why on earth are you doing: `''.join(map(bytes.decode, json_string))`? You just want `json_string.decode()`

Comment: @NewPythonUser Like that https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=The%20Terminator

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga because downloadPage() returns list and ```json_string.decode()``` doesn't work for list. I suppose my mistake is somewhere in ```str1 = ''.join(map(bytes.decode, json_string))``` but I can't manage to fix it.

Comment: **why are you using `urlopen(url).readlines()`**? Why return a list? Just use `urlopen(url).read()` That isn't your mistake. Your mistake is quite clear, that `dict` doesnt have that key, `"extract"`, why do you think it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your JSON object, then you have to traverse the whole object to get to the value you want to extract.

```
{
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{
      "pages":{
         "30327":{
            "pageid":30327,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"The Terminator",
            "extract":"The Terminator is a 1984 American science fiction film directed by James Cameron. It stars Arnold Schwarzenegger as the Terminator, a cyborg assassin sent back in time from 2029 to 1984 to kill Sarah Connor (Linda Hamilton), whose son will one day become a savior against machines in a post-apocalyptic future. Michael Biehn plays Kyle Reese, a  reverent soldier sent back in time to protect Sarah. The screenplay is credited to Cameron and producer Gale Anne Hurd, while co-writer William Wisher Jr. received a credit for additional dialogue. Executive producers John Daly and Derek Gibson of Hemdale Film Corporation were instrumental in financing and production.The Terminator topped the United States box office for two weeks and helped launch Cameron's film career and solidify Schwarzenegger's status as a leading man. Its success led to a franchise consisting of several sequels, a television series, comic books, novels and video games. In 2008, The Terminator was selected by the Library of Congress for preservation in the National Film Registry as \"culturally, historically, or aesthetically significant\"."
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Something like:

```
result = json["query"]["pages"]["30327"]["extract"]
```

But of course you should search for the property in a proper way, iterating over properties / arrays and testing if the keys exist.

## EDIT

If you know the structure is always the same, but the ID differs, then you can try something like this to handle arbitrary IDs.

```
for key, value in d["query"]["pages"].items():
   result = value["extract"]
   print(result)
```

Comment: So lets say I want to use it for another movie. How can I get the pageid? Say if I want to make it for https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Crimson%20Tide%20(film) the page id is 1317604

Answer (score 1):

JSON file have levels so if you want to get some values you should get via chains of keys:

```
parsed_json['query']['pages']['30327']['extract']
```